# Run a custom method immediately after Azure AD Authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, razor-pages

I have an ASP.NET Core Web App which successfully uses Azure AD Authentication. I would like to run a process immediately after a user logs in. I thought I might somehow handle the Redirect URI specified in the Azure app registration but I couldn't figure it out as much of the login process is nicely handled by the `.AddAzureAd()` method in my `Startup.cs`.

Can anyone suggest an easy way to call a method or redirect to a razor page after authentication? Preferably something which would not be circumvented by specifying a returnUrl in the initial request.

### Update

Between posting the question and seeing the answers I found what might be considered a hack:

Basically I created a service and injected it into my `_LoginPartial.cshtml` page and then call a method on the service.

```cs
...
@inject MyService myService
...
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    await MyService.MyCustomMethod();
...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For running code or changing the redirect url, you could configure `OpenIdConnectOptions`.

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
{
    options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
    {
        OnTokenValidated = ctx =>
        {
            ctx.Properties.RedirectUri = "/Home/Privacy";
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        },
    };
});
```

If you want to run code after authentication, you could place your code in the `OnTokenValidated`.

If you want to change the uri, you could replace `/Home/Privacy`.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the route in `Startup.cs` file. I used the sample [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect-aspnetcore).

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
            {
                sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddAzureAd(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options))
            .AddCookie();

            services.AddMvc();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default", 
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Contact}/{id?}");
            });
        }
```